# How can extract a value from .ini using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Here is a section in my .ini file

```
[section]
section[host] = "localhost"
section[username] = "user"
section[password] = "password.123"
section[db] = "dbname"
```

I want the values of section[host]. I know I am supposed to use regex for this. But not able to make it run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: ... And? Did you already tried something? Please post code you wrote!

Comment: `sed -nE 's/section\[host\] *= *"([^"]*)"/\1/p'`

Comment: @Cyrus whit 2'7kRep, 140 post and 6year, there is no new SO user!

Comment: @F.Hauri: He's acting like a new user, though.